# Javascript inheritance takes function of parents parent?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

So.. Here's my problem.. I have the following code (example):

```
var GameObject = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
 this.posX = posX;
 this.posY = posY;
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.health = 100;
 this.doDamage = function (damage) {
   //Do nothing..
 }
}

var Creature = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
 this.constructor(posX, posY, width, height);
 this.doDamage = function (damage) {
  this.health -= damage;
 }
}
Creature.prototype = new GameObject();

var Enemy = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
 this.constructor(posX, posY, width, height);
}
Enemy.prototype = new Creature();

var e = new Enemy(40,40,10,10);
e.doDamage(20);
```

The output of `e.doDamage` is the function as defined in `GameObject`. But I would expect it to be the function as defined in `Creature`. Why doesn't it use that one?

Comment: Maybe you should log the value of `this.constructor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that by the time you call the Enemy constructor, you've already overwritten `this.constructor` twice. So when you call `this.constructor` from your Enemy class, you're actually calling the `GameObject` constructor and bypassing the `Creature` constructor altogether. To fix this, you need to call the constructors explicitly.

So in your `Creature` class, you need to call the following:

```
GameObject.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
```

instead of

```
this.constructor(posX, posY, width, height);
```

and in your `Enemy` class you need to instead call the following:

```
Creature.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
```

---

Here is a working **live demo**:

```js
var GameObject = function(posX, posY, width, height) {
  console.log("GameObject Constructor Called");
  this.posX = posX;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.health = 100;
  this.doDamage = function(damage) {
    //Do nothing..
  }
}

var Creature = function(posX, posY, width, height) {
  console.log("Creature Constructor Called");
  GameObject.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
  this.doDamage = function(damage) {
    this.health -= damage;
  }
}
Creature.prototype = new GameObject();

var Enemy = function(posX, posY, width, height) {
  console.log("Enemy Constructor Called");
  Creature.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
}
Enemy.prototype = new Creature();

console.log("Setup Done");

var e = new Enemy(40, 40, 10, 10);
e.doDamage(20);

document.getElementById("output").textContent = e.health;
```

```html
<div>Initial Health: 100</div>
<div>20 health subtracted</div>
<div>Final Health: <span id="output" style="color: red;"></span></div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/5uq8rpe3/

Answer (score 0):

I think to solve this problem put the `Creature` function above the `GameObject` function

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Define your function in `prototype`, use `GameObject.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);` to extends the properties in parent, use `Creature.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);` to extends the function in parent and change the value of constructor property. For more information [JavaScript object oriented inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance)

```
var GameObject = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.health = 100;
}
GameObject.prototype.doDamage = function (damage) {
    //Do nothing..
}

var Creature = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
    GameObject.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
}
Creature.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);
Creature.prototype.constructor = Creature;
Creature.prototype.doDamage = function (damage) {
    this.health -= damage;
}

var Enemy = function (posX, posY, width, height) {
    Creature.call(this, posX, posY, width, height);
}
Enemy.prototype = Object.create(Creature.prototype);
Enemy.prototype.constructor = Enemy;

var e = new Enemy(40,40,10,10);
e.doDamage(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it use that one?

`constructor` starts out as an inherited property. When you define a function `F`, two objects are created: the function object itself, `F`, and a prototype object property of the function, `F.prototype`. The prototype object has a constructor property pointing to F: `F.prototype.constructor = F;`

If you now set `F.prototype` to a different object value, objects newly created by `F` will inherit their constructor property from the new prototype object you set. If you further create a prototype chain of objects, objects created based on the last prototype object generally inherit their constructor from the first object in the prototype chain. Which is why `this.constructor` in `Enemy` is calling `GameObject` instead of `Creature`.

Noting `constructor` values can be changed on javascript objects. A different way of calling a function as both a constructor and an inheritable method would be to attach it to its prototype object. E.G.

```
GameObject.prototype.setup = GameObject; // inherit GameObject as setup method
```